How to regenerate the windows/flutter folder in a Flutter project
I have a Flutter project and want to generaate the windows/flutter folder but I don't want to lose manual changes in windows/runner folder.
How I can achieve that?

Purpose

Backup the windows folder.
Delete the windows folder.
Use flutter create . to regenerate project.
Restore the manual changes from the backup to the new windows/runner folder.

Command line

cp -r windows windows_backup
rm -rf windows
flutter create .
cp -r windows_backup/runner/* windows/runner/


Results in "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:58 (include):  include could not find requested file: flutter/generated_plugins.cmake" which is indeed missing. That is the file I want regenewerated. Any ideas?

Looks like https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94874
